# How to check user has permitted back camera usage for my app in both iOS 6 and iOS 7

Tags: ios, camera

I know that iOS7 has new api for AVCaptureDevice : `authorizationStatusForMediaType:` can know the permission status of back camera, but in iOS 6, what is the way to know ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last , I find one way to work both in iOS 6 and iOS 7, here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)backCameraIsReady
{
    AVCaptureDevice *inputDevice = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *captureInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:inputDevice error:nil];
    if (!captureInput) {
        return NO;
    } else {
        return YES;
    }
}
```